# how to disable resize on html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to be able to disable resize of html page in javascript in onLoad method please any help as soon as you can

Comment: Need more specifics. Give some HTML that you're wanting to do this with. What do you mean by re-size?

Comment: are you trying to disable resizing of the browser window? or of the 'page' (presumably HTML document with a single wrapper element)??

Comment: I want the user not able to resize the window, I have set the size of it to 300*300 and don't want the user to be able to change it is size by maximize button or by dragging borders

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail you can put some road-blocks to stop the user from doing things, but in the end the client can really do whatever they want (e.g. disable JavaScript, or use a user-script, etc)

Comment: 300x300 is quite small. Is this some kind of a popup-window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a modal dialog instead of a popup. As an HTML element you will be able to control the styling however you want.